# SQL WHERE DateTime is Between

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this query here:

```
SELECT * 
FROM QuestionnaireAnswer 
WHERE dateCreated BETWEEN CAST('20/12/2015' AS datetime) AND CAST('22/12/2015' AS datetime)
```

but I keep getting this error, how come? and how do I fix it?

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: What locale is your server set to?

Comment: You're probably using the wrong date format. What software are you using?

Comment: it wouldn't be 'm/d/Y' instead of 'd/m/Y' ? that what i think when i read "out-of-range value"

Answer (score 8):

There are many formats supported by SQL Server - see the [MSDN Books Online on CAST and CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx). Most of those formats are **dependent** on what settings you have - therefore, these settings might work some times - and sometimes not.

The way to solve this is to use the (slightly adapted) **ISO-8601 date format** that is supported by SQL Server - this format works **always** - regardless of your SQL Server language and dateformat settings.

The [ISO-8601 format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180878.aspx) is supported by SQL Server comes in two flavors:

- `YYYYMMDD` for just dates (no time portion); note here: **no dashes!**, that's very important! `YYYY-MM-DD` is **NOT** independent of the dateformat settings in your SQL Server and will **NOT** work in all situations!

or:

- `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS` for dates and times - note here: this format *has* dashes (but they *can* be omitted), and a fixed `T` as delimiter between the date and time portion of your `DATETIME`.

This is valid for SQL Server 2000 and newer. In your concrete case, use this `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE dateCreated BETWEEN '20151220' AND '20151222'
```

and you don't even need any explicit `CAST` operations (or if you want to use an explicit `CAST` - then I'd suggest you cast to a `DATE` datatype - rather than `DATETIME`).

If you use SQL Server 2008 or newer and the `DATE` datatype (only `DATE` - **not** `DATETIME`!), then you can indeed also use the `YYYY-MM-DD` format and that will work, too, with any settings in your SQL Server.

Don't ask me why this whole topic is so tricky and somewhat confusing - that's just the way it is. But with the `YYYYMMDD` format, you should be fine for any version of SQL Server and for any language and dateformat setting in your SQL Server.

The recommendation for SQL Server 2008 and newer is to use `DATE` if you only need the date portion, and `DATETIME2(n)` when you need both date and time. You should try to start phasing out the `DATETIME` datatype if ever possible

Comment: You can have a time portion with YYYYMMDD.  Ex: '20151220 2:45 pm' or '20151220 14:45'

Comment: @GMastros: If you want to convert to  `DATETIME` (or better: `DATETIME2(n)`) - yes, you can also specify a time portion as mentioned in my response: `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS` (with the `T` being a fixed delimiter between date and time portions)

Comment: The point I was trying to make is that 'YYYYMMDD HH:MM' is also acceptable, completely safe and absolutely unambiguous.

Comment: @GMastros: sorry, I misunderstood - but yes, your format is also just fine, with all the European languages and with the `DATETIME` datatype - thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule when comparing dates in SQL Server don't use a format specific to a locale, use the universal `ISO 8601` format `'yyyy/MM/dd'` so the query becomes:

```
SELECT * 
FROM QuestionnaireAnswer 
WHERE dateCreated BETWEEN CAST('2015/12/20' AS datetime) AND CAST('2015/12/22' AS datetime)
```

You could also use one that is specific to a locale but you would have to ensure that the date format on the server always remains the same across all servers your code will connect to.

Comment: If you want to cast to a `DATE`, your string literals are fine - but to cast to a `DATETIME`, this won't work always - this is still settings dependent - you need to use `YYYYMMDD` (**no dashes at all**) to be totally safe, for `DATETIME`. Just try `SET LANGUAGE German` and then run `SELECT CAST('2015/12/20' AS datetime)` and you'll see a nice, red error message ...

Comment: Thanks I wasn't aware of that, I have never actually come across a situation where the slashes have failed, I will keep that in mind from now on.

Comment: Pretty much all the European languages (even **British English**!) will fail - but only in conjunction with `DATETIME` - and since this is only a date, I'd much rather just cast to a `DATE` alone anyway

Comment: Any idea why those locales don't allow slashes? Do they carry some special meaning or just a cultural rule?

Comment: When you have slashes in your string literal, non-US locales seems to interpret the dates as `yyyy/dd/MM` and thus your `2015/12/20` is the 12th day of the 20th month (ERROR!) of 2015 ...

Comment: Interesting, all this time I was under the impression yyyy/MM/dd was the ISO standard not YYYYMMDD thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using [CONVERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/ms187928.aspx) you can write something like that:

```
SELECT * 
FROM QuestionnaireAnswer 
WHERE
dateCreated BETWEEN CONVERT(datetime, '20/12/2015', 103)
AND CONVERT(datetime, '22/12/2015', 103);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the locale settings on your server.  My bet is that you are set for a US date format, but the date you have there is not in a US format.

More on querying the locale settings [here](http://visakhm.blogspot.com/2012/09/getting-os-locale-settings-from-sql.html).

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208133/set-locale-of-a-sql-server-2005) has numerous ways to adjust the locale settings for SQL, including by user.

If you don't have permissions to change the locale for the whole server, you can change your locale within a session [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174398.aspx). Note that SET LANGUAGE automatically sets the DATEFORMAT , but you can [set the DATEFORMAT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx) by itself.

To test this, try reversing the date and month in your date.  Like so:

```
SELECT * 
FROM QuestionnaireAnswer 
WHERE dateCreated BETWEEN CAST('12/20/2015' AS datetime) AND CAST('12/22/2015' AS datetime)
```

Or try putting the date in a ["locale insensitive format"](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2007/10/22/SQL-Server-The-one-and-only-locale-insensitive-date-format.aspx) like yyyymmdd HH:mm:ss.fff .

Answer (score -1):

If column is a date field then you should do this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM QuestionnaireAnswer 
WHERE dateCreated BETWEEN TO_DATE('20-DEC-2015') AND TO_DATE('22-DEC-2015')
```

May not be 100% accurate depending on architecture and configuration.

Comment: to_date is for oracle, not MS SQL: http://www.connectsql.com/2011/04/sql-server-basics-todate-function-in.html

Comment: He didnt mention Microsoft at all.

Comment: It's tagged as sql-server, which is Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: I stand corrected I didnt see the tag, im a noob to the community, but just to clarify I did say "May not be 100% accurate depending on architecture and configuration." which covers the Microsoft / Oracle difference.

Comment: Not a problem, if you are unsure what a tag represents, you can hover over it to view it's description.